# Insert new siblings with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to go through a selection of paragraphs with d3 and conditionally add 
 elements in between some of them.

I'm currently using a mix of d3 and plain DOM stuff:

```
diagram.each(function (d, i) {
  if (currentRow !== d.row) {
    currentRow += 1;
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(br, this);
  }
});
```

Is there a way to do this bit with d3?

```
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(br, this);
```

In English: I'm trying to insert a break element after the current paragraph element. Append acts on a parent, and insert would be nice, but I have no way, that I know of, to reference this current paragraph in the second parameter of insert: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert

Any pointers?

Comment: Unless you modify the data that you're using to create the paragraphs in the first place to include those breaks (and then use the usual D3 data binding pattern), it doesn't sound like D3 is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

var br = d3.select("svg").append("br") ?

is this not what you want ? I don't have enough experience to comment :((

Comment: Thanks for the effort, AJ : )